# Can we fill rows of dataframe column of 1 dataframe equal to column header of another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 1 dataframe that looks like this

```
df1
company  2022-03-14 00:00:00    2022-03-15 00:00:00       2022-03-16 00:00:00
a             1                          1                          2
b             1                          1                          1 
c             1                          0                          1 
d             1                          2                          2
```

I have another dataframe that looks like below

```
df2
company numbers present
a           NaN
b           NaN
c           NaN
d           NaN
```

I want to population the 'numbers present' column in df2 with dates from df1 and number of rows with that date should be the numbers appearing below the datetime column headers. Final output df3 should look like below

```
df3
company     numbers present
a             2022-03-14
a             2022-03-15
a             2022-03-16
a             2022-03-16
b             2022-03-14
b             2022-03-15
b             2022-03-16
c             2022-03-14
c             2022-03-16
d             2022-03-14
d             2022-03-15
d             2022-03-15
d             2022-03-16
d             2022-03-16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `df.melt` and `df.index.repeat`:

```
new_df = df.melt(id_vars='company').pipe(lambda x: x.loc[x.index.repeat(x.value)]).drop('value', axis=1).sort_values('company').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
   company             variable
0        a  2022-03-14-00:00:00
1        a  2022-03-15-00:00:00
2        a  2022-03-16-00:00:00
3        a  2022-03-16-00:00:00
4        b  2022-03-14-00:00:00
5        b  2022-03-15-00:00:00
6        b  2022-03-16-00:00:00
7        c  2022-03-14-00:00:00
8        c  2022-03-16-00:00:00
9        d  2022-03-14-00:00:00
10       d  2022-03-15-00:00:00
11       d  2022-03-15-00:00:00
12       d  2022-03-16-00:00:00
13       d  2022-03-16-00:00:00
```